# Why does Program showing same output on removing Synchronized keyword from method and static object ?

Tags: java, multithreading, static, synchronization

**doubt** :I was trying something new by editing code. When i removed Synchronized keyword from **SumArray method** of class SyncSumArray and Static from **static SyncSumArray** present in the **SumThread** got suprised by output displayed by code. Both  version of program return   **same Value of  Sum**.
does this happening due to static object or something else is responsible for this ??

```
      class SyncSumArray
>     {
>         private int sum=0;
>         
>        synchronized  int sumArray(int nums[])
>         {
>           sum=0; // reset sum
>             
>             for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++)
>           {  sum+=nums[i];
>             System.out.println("Running total for "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" is "+ sum);
>             try{
>                 Thread.sleep(100);  // allow task switch
>             }
>             catch(InterruptedException e)
>             {
>                 System.out.println("Threadinterrupted");
>             }
>         }
>         return sum;
>     }
>     }
>     class SumThread implements Runnable
>     { Thread thrd;
>        static SyncSumArray sa=new SyncSumArray();
>         int a[];
>         int answer;
>         
>         SumThread(String name,int nums[])
>         {   thrd=new Thread(this,name);
>             a=nums;
>             thrd.start();
>         }
>         
>         // Begin execution of new Thread
>         
>         public void run()
>         {
>             int sum;
>             System.out.println(thrd.getName()+" starting.");
>             
>             answer=sa.sumArray(a);
>             System.out.println(" Sum for "+ thrd.getName()+" is " +answer);
>             System.out.println(thrd.getName() + " terminating.");
>         }
>     }
>     class DemoSync
>     {
>         public static void main(String args[])
>         {
>             int a[]={1,2,3,4,5};
>             
>             SumThread mt1=new SumThread("Child #1",a);
>              SumThread mt2=new SumThread("Child #2",a);
>              
>              try
>              {
>                  mt1.thrd.join();
>                  mt2.thrd.join();
>                 }
>                 catch(InterruptedException e)
>                 { System.out.println("Main thread interrupted.");
>                 }
>             }
>         }
```

Comment: Can you clarify why you expect to get different results? The only difference I see is that with synchornized it should take about 100 ms longer. You get the same result because you are not performing any operations which are not thread safe.

Comment: And hint: there is absolutely no need to put those '>' chars into your source code. To the contrary, they make reading your source code **harder** than it needed to be!

Comment: @ Peter Lawrey i read in the book if we remove synchronized keyword then any number of threads  may use it concurrently which will change value of sum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is: iterating an array and summing up all its element, using a "local" counter is not something that will change in any way, no matter how many threads are counting in parallel.

In order to see "side effects" of multi-threading, you need to work with some kind of activity where your threads **write** to some shared data structure! Otherwise, each thread just does its own work; completely independent of what the other threads are doing!

Comment: Yes. Using static global variable could throw some light on how codes in a multi-threading environment could be harmful to you at times. @Lalit Kumar

Comment: ok i got ur point.That y they had  used static SumArray sa=new SumArray().  By the way Can u tell me what is name of above static type(not class member or method)

Comment: @Lalitkumar are you talking about a *field*?